# Subtract with previous index where index is not a number using awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, indexing

i would like to subtract values from previous values but a condition must be satisfied.

File:

```
2022-02-01 01:00:00|abc|2001|5
2022-02-01 01:00:00|abc|2002|10
2022-02-01 01:01:00|abc|2001|6
2022-02-01 01:01:00|abc|2002|11
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2001|10
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2002|11
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2003|2
```

Desired output:

```
2022-02-01 01:00:00|abc|2001|5
2022-02-01 01:00:00|abc|2002|10
2022-02-01 01:01:00|abc|2001|1
2022-02-01 01:01:00|abc|2002|1
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2001|4
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2002|0
2022-02-01 01:02:00|abc|2003|2
```

I tried with awk but couldnt reach the previous index to subtract the value

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}{a[$1,$2,$3]=$4}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]-a[i-1] }' file
```

Comment: I know you are subtracting `6-5`, `11-10`, `10-6`, `11-11` but I'm not able to understand what you meant with *"subtract with previous index where index is not a number using awk"*. What is the condition? I see all index are numbers

Comment: `man awk`: "The order that var transverses the indices of array is not defined." for a `for ( var in array )` statement. So you can't evaluate a "previous index" reliably unless you use sequential integers (e.g. line number) for index and run the loop across these incrementeing integers.

Comment: If the index is `2022-02-01 01:01:00,abc,2002` then you need to split and reconstruct the index after calculating `(2002 - 1)` separately. Further, the index syntax permits `,` separators but the stored index of `a[i]` will be separated by the value of the SUBSEP variable, not an actual comma. As @RudiC notes, the output sequence is random. Unless the input is huge (> 1GB), I would store all the input in `a[FNR]`, and use integer indexing to find the previous matching recode, and then again to output the final results.

Comment: Regarding `but a condition must be satisfied` - what condition?

Comment: By condition i mean same reference abc|2001 value should be subtracted by abc|2001 but the time should be the previous entry. The problem how to make index to number to traverse between current time and the previous time.

Comment: @ammar do you have to use `awk`?

Comment: Actually i have to do it in one line of code without piping thats what i aim i am able to achieve my goal by using past and redirect to a file then awk and subtract but i would like to keep my lines as neat as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you want to do is this:

```bash
awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="|" '{ a=$4;if($3 in dict)$4-=dict[$3]; dict[$3]=a}1' file
```

I'm using `associative arrays` in awk for storing as keys the years you have and their value would be the last column.
For example, the array should look like this:

```
dict[2001] = "4th column"
dict[2002] = "4th column"
dict[2003] = "4th column"
....
```

So the `dict`  keys/values are like this:

```c
dict[2001] = "5"
dict[2002] = "10"
dict[2001] = "6"
dict[2002] = "11"
dict[2001] = "10"
dict[2002] = "11"
dict[2003] = "2" # this never changes because you have only one 2003 as year.
```

So with the awk code: `a=$4;if($3 in dict)$4-=dict[$3]; dict[$3]=a` I'm able to subtract the 4th column with the last value stored in `dict` according to the current key year. **$3 is the year** and **$4 is the index/value**

---

As you said it in the comments it seems the `keys` for the associative array should be `abc|year`. If so, then you should use this:

```bash
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{a=$4; if(($2,$3) in dict)$4-=dict[$2,$3]; dict[$2,$3]=a }1' file
```

Comment: appreciate your effort @Edgar-Magallon. I have also thought of such a solution but yours is simpler. my solution was like this: `awk -F"|" '{if (length(a[$1]) == 0) {a[$1]=i; c[i]=$1; i=i+1}; b[$1"|"$2"|"$3]=$4}END{for (i in b) print i"|"b[i]-b[c[a[substr(i,1,19)]-1]substr(i,20)]}'`

Comment: @ammar Maybe there are simpler ways that mine too. I thought `associative arrays` was not supported in `awk`. But I tried it and it worked. `Awk` is very powerful as well as `sed`, `grep` and many others Unix tools.

Answer (score 1):

Using `miller`:

```
mlr --nidx --fs '|' put '$delta = is_present(@last[$3]) ? $4 - @last[$3]  : $4; @last[$3] = $4; unset $4' file
```

In this command fourth field is stored in `@last` indexed on third field. `is_present` sees if `@last[$3]` is true (that is there is variable present indexed on third field of current record) then the difference between two value is printed. Otherwise it prints fourth field.

And at last fourth field is unset.

If first values are not required then the following will do.

```
 mlr --nidx --fs '|' step -g 3 -a delta -f 4 file
```